# asp.net mvc area routed as part of another area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an area, `Foo`, that has a single route mapped: `foo/{controller}/{action}/{id}`.

I also have another area, `Bar`,  that is essentially a sub-component of this area.  It has a mapped route of `foo/bar/{controller}/{action}/{id}`.

So, for instance, I have a controller named `BazController` within my `Bar` area, so I can have a route that looks like `foo/bar/baz`.

The problem with this is that the routes don't seem to resolve for this scenario, as it appears that my mapped routes are looking for a controller named `BarController` instead of mapping to the route declared with `foo/bar/{controller}/{action}/{id}`

I'm assuming there's some fundamental design concept that I've unwittingly violated... if that's the case, how should I organize this instead of having two areas?

My primary understanding of url routing comes from a Django background, where you could do stuff like reference separate url files and all routes are processed in a top-down fashion.  I don't know how route mapping precedence is determined with asp.net mvc, and have no idea how ordering of route registration is done with areas.

**UPDATE**

I used Phil Haack's route debugger as @zLan suggested, and it is indeed matching on both of my mapped routes, and for some reason taking precedence to the route specified in `Foo` area over the one specified in the `Bar` area.

I debugged it further and specified both of the routes in Global.asax instead of in their respective `RegisterArea` methods as @mfanto suggested, and it seems to choose the route that was declared first.

My follow up question, then, is: how do I specify/determine which area will get registered first?  And if that's not a reliable convention to follow, is there an acceptable way to declare these routes in such a fashion that the url `foo/bar/baz` will resolve to my `Bar` area, without having to declare them all in `Global.asax`?

Comment: Phil Haack has a great [Route Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) to let you know where your routes are going.

Comment: Can you paste the list of routes you've created so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the order in which area routes would get registered.  Since I didn't find any conclusive documentation on how area routes get mapped, and don't think it's safe to rely on any particular ordering, I went ahead and created a new class to encapsulate the routing that I could call from within a different routes file.  This basically "modularizes" an area, so that it can be used as a set of routes to be appended to some other url prefix.

The basic idea is to emulate [Django's ability to include other urlconfs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs) so that I could do something like the following within `FooAreaRegistration`:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    new BarAreaModule().RegisterRoutes(namePrefix:"bar", urlPrefix:"foo/", context.Routes);

    context.MapRoute("foo_default", "foo/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new{controller="Default", action="Index", id=UrlParameter.Optional});
}
```

and have all the routes get registered in an ordered fashion so that `foo/bar` doesn't get confused with the `"foo_default" route.

The following is the entire source of the AreaModule class, for anyone that's interested:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Gov.Wa.Hecb.UI.Portal.Areas
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Allows a group of functionality to be registered to any given url prefix.  This is to be used to replace an Area in cases 
    /// where an Area is either a sub-module to another area, or if an area's functionality is to be parameterized and reused in 
    /// multiple urls.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class AreaModule
    {
        public abstract string AreaName { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Registers all routes necessary for this Module to function with the given url prefix
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="namePrefix"></param>
        /// <param name="urlPrefix">a slash-appended string representing the url to match up to the module</param>
        /// <param name="routes"></param>
        public void RegisterRoutes(string namePrefix, string urlPrefix, RouteCollection routes)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(namePrefix))
                throw new ArgumentException("namePrefix cannot be null or empty", "namePrefix");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(urlPrefix))
                throw new ArgumentException("urlPrefix cannot be null or empty", "urlPrefix");
            if (routes == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("routes");

            var context = new AreaModuleContext(AreaName, namePrefix, urlPrefix, routes);
            var thisNamespace = GetType().Namespace;
            if (thisNamespace != null)
                context.Namespaces.Add(thisNamespace + ".*");

            RegisterRoutes(context);
        }

        protected abstract void RegisterRoutes(AreaModuleContext context);
    }

    public class AreaModuleContext
    {
        #region Private

        private readonly HashSet<string> _namespaces = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public AreaModuleContext(string areaName, string namePrefix, string urlPrefix, RouteCollection routes, object state = null)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(areaName))
                throw new ArgumentException("areaName cannot be null or empty", "areaName");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(namePrefix))
                throw new ArgumentException("namePrefix cannot be null or empty", "namePrefix");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(urlPrefix))
                throw new ArgumentException("urlPrefix cannot be null or empty", "urlPrefix");
            if (routes == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("routes");

            AreaName = areaName;
            NamePrefix = namePrefix;
            UrlPrefix = urlPrefix;
            Routes = routes;
            State = state;
        }


        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public string AreaName { get; private set; }

        public string NamePrefix { get; private set; }

        public string UrlPrefix { get; private set; }

        public ICollection<string> Namespaces
        {
            get { return _namespaces; }
        }

        public RouteCollection Routes { get; private set; }

        public object State { get; private set; }

        #endregion

        #region Route Mapping

        public Route MapRoute(string name, string url)
        {
            return MapRoute(name, url, (object) null /* defaults */);
        }

        public Route MapRoute(string name, string url, object defaults)
        {
            return MapRoute(name, url, defaults, (object) null /* constraints */);
        }

        public Route MapRoute(string name, string url, object defaults, object constraints)
        {
            return MapRoute(name, url, defaults, constraints, null /* namespaces */);
        }

        public Route MapRoute(string name, string url, string[] namespaces)
        {
            return MapRoute(name, url, null /* defaults */, namespaces);
        }

        public Route MapRoute(string name, string url, object defaults, string[] namespaces)
        {
            return MapRoute(name, url, defaults, null /* constraints */, namespaces);
        }

        public Route MapRoute(string name, string url, object defaults, object constraints, string[] namespaces)
        {
            if (namespaces == null && Namespaces != null)
                namespaces = Namespaces.ToArray();

            var route = Routes.MapRoute(NamePrefix + name, UrlPrefix + url, defaults, constraints, namespaces);
            route.DataTokens["area"] = AreaName;

            // disabling the namespace lookup fallback mechanism keeps this areas from accidentally picking up
            // controllers belonging to other areas
            var useNamespaceFallback = (namespaces == null || namespaces.Length == 0);
            route.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = useNamespaceFallback;

            return route;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does adding something like the following to RegisterRoutes() in Global.asax work for the route?

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "foo/bar/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { area = "Bar", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Just to echo zLan's comment, Phil's Route Debugger is great for fixing issues like this.

Comment: by declaring both the routes in `Global.asax` it seems to accept the first route declared.  Doing it like this seems to defeat the purpose of keeping all your route registrations within the specified area.  Perhaps what I'm doing by "nesting" areas requires me to do so anyway?